# Ajax multiple service calls in a synchronous manner

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am writing a page in which we have am having multiple rest service calls to achieve my functionality. And to add more information, I have to pass the response of serviceCall-ONE as the request of serviceCall-TWO. same applies for Servicecall-THREE also

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    fun1(); /* Actual called functions are written in a separate methods */
    fun2();
    fun3();
});
```

Is there any way to achieve the above mentioned functionality without using .Done or .Then.
The reason is dont want to implement the .done callback is that i should be able to write individual unit test cases separately for all the 3 methods and test cases can be independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make this requests via the Caolan's Async library - https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use unit testing there's no reason why you couldn't just "mock" the done callback with say an empty function like function () {} - this is standard practice.

Have a look at the sinon library
http://sinonjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with 3 ajax-functions.
Try something like that:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    ajax_function1();
});
```

the ajax functions could look like this:

```
function ajax_function1(){
var url = "http://myurl.com";
var data = "some data";
jQuery.ajax({
            async:      true,
            type:       'POST',
            url:        url,
            data:       data,
            dataType:  "json", 
            success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            if(data.status == 'success'){
                                //call your second function
                                ajax_function2(data);
                            } else {
                            } 
                        }
            });
}
```

etc.